# User, Group and Other in the chmod command

Tags: permissions, chmod, user-management

I think I basically understood the point with the seven levels of authorization with the `chmod` command. However I'm not sure what is meant by user, group and other. 
What's the difference between group and other? 
If I set `chmod myFile 700` from `me@myComputer`, will I still have the right to access `myFile` from `root@myComputer`?
Under which circumstances can one user re-write the authorizations for a file when this user does not have write access on it (using sudo I guess, but I'm not sure)?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not seven levels of authorization. There are basically three for each of user, group and others.

The number can go up to seven but it's just a sum of three levels.

- 4 = read acces
- 2 = write access
- 1 = allow to execute (for scripts and binaries)

Whatever you want to have from these permissions, add it up and you get a number.

Now do these for every of the three cases.

- First digit = That's what is granted for the owner of the file
- Second digit = Is what's granted for all members of the group of the
  file
- Third digit = What's granted for everyone, regardless of username or
  group

Hint: It's a bit special for directories so if you understood it for files you should read into how it applies for directories...

Comment: Who is the owner, the creator or the user the file was created inside of its home directory? What is defining a group? These questions may have obvious answer, but it's still unclear to me.

Comment: The user who creates a file is by default the owner of the file. So most files in the home directory of a user end up being owned by that user. For the rest it gets too complex to answer here directly so this shoud help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: And here: https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/